# Building automatic strings based on a variable

Tags: powershell

I have a variable called: `$backendSubnet`

This variable currently contains 4 entries, when I do `$backendSubnet.Count` it returns '**4**'

This number of entries will change each time the script is run. What I need to do it automatically break out (based on the number of entries) in this instance there's 4 - to be used in another CmdLet, see.....

```
-Subnet $backendSubnet1,$backendSubnet2,$backendSubnet3,$backendSubnet2
```

I need to automate breaking this out arranged like this above.

I have tried the following, bit I think I am on the wrong track:

```
$max = $backendSubnet.Count -1;0..$max | % {$backendSubnetArray += $backendSubnet[$_]}
```

Comment: It appears that the cmdlet accepts an array for the `-Subnet` parameter.  I would think that `-Subnet $backendSubnet` would work.

Comment: No, this has too many entries (4 subnets in total), need to break them out like my example above, with commas between.

Comment: @MarcKean No, you don't. Your comma-separated list of variables is an array as well. There's no difference between that and passing the original array. If `$backendSubnet` contains subnets you don't want to pass: remove them from the array with a `Where-Object` filter.

Comment: Good point, I'll try that, I'll work under the assumption that I can specify an array, i can build one by using   = @()

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest initializing a new array to a predefined size, then copy N elements from the `$backendSubnet` into the new array.  Then rinse and repeat.

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $backendSubnet.Count; $i += $numToCopy)
{
    $numToCopy = [Math]::Min($backendSubnet.Count - $i, $max)
    $subset = new-object object[] $numToCopy
    [Array]::Copy($backendSubnet, $i, $subset, 0, $numToCopy)

    SomeCmdlet -Subnet $subset
}
```

Comment: When running that above, $numToCopy is blank and $backendSubnet.Count equals 4